# AngularJS unit testing with ReSharper

Tags: angularjs, resharper, jasmine

I'm trying to get Jasmine unit tests for an AngularJS controller running with the ReSharper test runner so I can run my client and server-side tests in one place within VS 2012.

I'm running into an issue where the ReSharper test runner is failing with a message of "Inconclusive: Test wasn't run". The same test runs fine using the test runner that comes with the AngularJS Seed project.

Here's my simple test for troubleshooting:

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/angular/angular.js"/>
/// <reference path="~/tests/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js"/>
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/app/controllers.js"/>

'use strict';

describe('controllers', function(){
  beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));

  it('should ....', inject(function() {
      expect(1).toEqual(1);
  }));
});
```

I suspect it has something to do with my references because if I remove the call to `inject`, my test runs fine. However, `inject` is defined in angular-mocks.js (which I'm referencing) so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hunch about ReSharper tripping over inline `inject` is right, it seems to expect `function` instead when it parses file to get list of tests. I've worked around by moving `inject`s into either `beforeEach` or into the body of the `it` and that made ReSharper happy again. Btw, I've also added reference to *jasmine.js* at the top (before other references) to get rid of ReSharper's warnings about undefined Jasmine globals.

Comment: What version of Jasmine are you using there?

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue about this ReSharper problem at their tracker at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-383328 - you can vote for it to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this page. I disabled the option "Shadow-copy assemblies being tested", and it worked.
[Test method is inconclusive: Test wasn't run. Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311108/test-method-is-inconclusive-test-wasnt-run-error)

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper set file jasmine.js after all references.
angular-mock.js will not find jasmine and will skip creation window.module and window.injec functions

I created jasmine2.js and set it as first reference. I did empty jasmine.js and set it as second reference.

After all my test did work